# C# dictionary, how to get the a specific value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created a dictionary, and I want the user to write the city ( kommune) and then get the value (procent) displayed in a text box called txtKommuneresultalt

I am new to C#, so I hope someone can help me

I have tried searching for days now, nothing works.I am using Windowsforms, and have the buttonHandler ready

this so far is my code:

```
Dictionary<double, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, string>();
double procent = Convert.ToDouble(txtKommuneresultat.Text);
string kommune = txtKommuneInput.Text;


dictionary.Add(11.44, "Faxe");
dictionary.Add(4.29, "Greve");
dictionary.Add(7.11, "Gulborgsund");
dictionary.Add(7.86, " Holbæk");
dictionary.Add(5.67, "Kalundborg");
dictionary.Add(4.99, "Køge");
dictionary.Add(7.28, "Lejre");
dictionary.Add(2.67, "Lolland");
dictionary.Add(4.07, "Næstved");
dictionary.Add(1.21, "Odsherred");
dictionary.Add(5.02, "Ringsted");
dictionary.Add(13.23, "Slagelse");
dictionary.Add(20.75, "Solrød");
dictionary.Add(1.81, "Sorø");
dictionary.Add(5.50, "Stevns");
dictionary.Add(1.29, "Vordingborg");

txtKommuneresultat.Show();
```

Comment: the first line of my code is this :
Dictionary<double, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, string>();

            double procent = Convert.ToDouble(txtKommuneresultat.Text);
            string kommune = txtKommuneInput.Text;

Comment: You want a `Dictionary<string, double>`, since the key is the string value. Also, you should only be populating your dictionary once and then only referencing it later on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**How to fish:**

Here is a good start for learning about Dictionary in C#:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8

Also, MSDN have a lot of useful resources there, please, feel free to explore.

**How to do it (I think this will be specific to your case, I divided into two options, using city name as key or using percentage as key):**

```
using System;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        //Part 1: Using percentage as Key
        Dictionary<double, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, string>();

        dictionary.Add(11.44, "Faxe");          
        //(...)         
        dictionary.Add(1.29, "Vordingborg");

        //Here is Komune
        dictionary.Add(5.89, "Komune");

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(5.89)){
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found: {0}!", dictionary[5.89]));
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found!");
        }



        //Part 2: Using the string as Key
        Dictionary<string,double> dictionaryStringPercent = new Dictionary<string,double>();

        dictionaryStringPercent.Add("Faxe",11.44);                  
        //(...)         
        dictionaryStringPercent.Add("Vordingborg",1.0);

        //Here is Komune
        dictionaryStringPercent.Add("Komune",5.89);

        if (dictionaryStringPercent.ContainsKey("Komune")){
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found: {0}!", dictionaryStringPercent["Komune"]));
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything useful, and should the link ever break, it will truly be useless. Also, the linked page is in Portuguese.

Comment: @Abion47 The box in the top of the page linked appears to read, _This article was machine translated._ (in Portuguese).

Comment: THANK you all SO much :)
it is working like a charm - changed the dictionary to (string, double)

Answer (score 5):

The first type in a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is the *key* and the second is the *value*. A dictionary allow you to look up a *value* based on that value's *key*.

Currently, you have a `double` as the first type (the key) and a `string` as the second type (the value). This would allow you to look up a `string` value by using a `double` value as a key.

But wait. Your doubles are representing a percentage, while your strings represent a city name. You want to look up a percentage, based on the city name. So the `string` should be the *key* in your dictionary, not the double.

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

This allow you to get a specific double value by providing the right string:

```
var percentage = dictionary["Gulborgsund"];
```

Since the lookup will be based on user input (which is usually unreliable), it would probably be best to use the [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
double percentage;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(userInput, out percentage)) 
{
    // Use percentage
}
else 
{
    // Could not retrieve value
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to elaborate? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Unless there's a restriction that OP didn't mention, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @MAV i think because you tried to correct the way OP had the dictionary. I personally agree, that state city should be the key and the double the value

Answer (score 0):

```
        string userInput = txtKommuneInput.Text;
        double procent;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(userInput, out procent))

            txtKommuneresultat.Text = procent.ToString();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)